# Why is this query only showing one result when it is supposed to show 2?

Tags: php, mysqli

num_rows shows 2 rows of results but the while loop is only showing one row.
How can I show both rows with the while loop?

```
$getTheImage = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(USERNAME,MEM_KEY) AS USERNAME, AVATAR FROM MEMBERS WHERE DEV_ADD=AES_ENCRYPT('".$dipaddB."',MEM_KEY)");
$getTheImage->execute();
$getTheImage->bind_result($username, $avatar);
$getTheImage->store_result();


echo $getTheImage->num_rows;
if($avatar == ''){$ava = 'styles/imagesio/anon_small.png';}else{$ava =  $avatar;}
while($getTheImage->fetch()){ 
$LoggedAccounts  = "<div class=\"boxHead\">Auto Login Accounts</div>";
$LoggedAccounts .= "<div class=\"resCon\"><button class=\"quickButton\" onclick=\"loggmein();\" id=\"".$username."\"><img class=\"avatQuick\" src=\"".$ava."\" alt=\"ioguy\"><div class=\"usrClass\">".$username."</div></button></div>";
}

$getTheImage->close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite on every iteration. Move the initialization prior to the `while`.

You also are misusing prepared statements. You should bind the value.

```
$getTheImage = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(USERNAME,MEM_KEY) AS USERNAME, AVATAR FROM MEMBERS WHERE DEV_ADD=AES_ENCRYPT(?, MEM_KEY)");
$getTheImage->bind_param('s', $dipaddB);
$getTheImage->execute();
$getTheImage->bind_result($username, $avatar);
$getTheImage->store_result();


echo $getTheImage->num_rows;
$ava = ($avatar == '') ? 'styles/imagesio/anon_small.png' : $avatar;
$LoggedAccounts = '';
while($getTheImage->fetch()){ 
     $LoggedAccounts .= "<div class=\"boxHead\">Auto Login Accounts</div>";
     $LoggedAccounts .= "<div class=\"resCon\"><button class=\"quickButton\" onclick=\"loggmein();\" id=\"".$username."\"><img class=\"avatQuick\" src=\"".$ava."\" alt=\"ioguy\"><div class=\"usrClass\">".$username."</div></button></div>";
}
$getTheImage->close();
```

Comment: I added ternary in place of the conditional. You might even be able to use this query though to have the return just be the avatar or default... `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(USERNAME,MEM_KEY) AS USERNAME, coalesce(NULLIF(AVATAR, ''), 'styles/imagesio/anon_small.png') as AVATAR FROM MEMBERS WHERE DEV_ADD=AES_ENCRYPT(?, MEM_KEY)` thats untested though. Then you'd just do `$getTheImage->bind_result($username, $ava);`

Answer (score 1):

$LoggedAccounts will be overwritten each time the loop executes. Try this.

```
while($getTheImage->fetch()){ 
    $LoggedAccounts .= "<div class=\"boxHead\">Auto Login Accounts</div>";
    $LoggedAccounts .= "<div class=\"resCon\"><button class=\"quickButton\" onclick=\"loggmein();\" id=\"".$username."\"><img class=\"avatQuick\" src=\"".$ava."\" alt=\"ioguy\"><div class=\"usrClass\">".$username."</div></button></div>";
}
```

Comment: `$LoggedAccounts` would still need to be initialized otherwise a notice will be thrown.